# SvelteKit: Type Issues with Data Loading

Tags: javascript, types, svelte, sveltekit

I am having trouble understanding how to properly load data to my page.
Here is my current project structure:

```
src/
├── components/
│   └── Post.svelte
└── routes/
    ├── +page.svelte
    ├── +page.server.js
    └── +layout.svelte
```

I am trying to load data to `+page.svelte` using the load function in `+page.server.js` and send it to `Post.svelte`. I am using `+page.server.js` because I load the data from a Firebase Real-Time database. However, when I load the data from `page.server.js` and try to access the `post` field, I get an error saying that the field is not in the JSON.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

### +page.server.js

Currently, this page returns the same basic JSON. Note that I am using the `PageServerLoad` type because I am using +page.server.js instead of +page.js.

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export function load({ params }) {
  return {
    post: {
      "quote": "Something quote",
      "description": "Something description"
    }
  };
}
```

### +page.svelte

```
<script>
    import Post from '../components/Post.svelte'
    /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
    export let data;
</script>

<h1>Lyrics and Quotes</h1>
<Post postData={data.post}/> // Error here: property 'post' does not exist in '{}'.
```

### +Post.svelte

```
<script>
    /** @type {import('../routes/$types').PageData} */
    export let postData;
</script>

<p>
    This is a post.
    {postData.quote} //Error here: property 'quote' does not exist in '{}'.
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */` results in the type `{ post: { quote: string; description: string; }; }`, so you must make sure to pick the `post` property:

```html
<script>
    /** @type {import('../routes/$types').PageData["post"]} */
    export let postData;
</script>

<p>
    This is a post.
    {postData.quote}
</p>
```